# React-Toastify is not displaying properly

Tags: reactjs, react-toastify

I am using React Toastify in my React.js file where i want to display a toast message that user successfully added.
Therefore I used API to send the data to add in my database using Spring Boot which is working fine and i am using axios to display toast message when data is added to the database successfully.
But The toast pop up is not displaying properly as well as it get to huge when without any styling.
[image: This type of image appear when i click on submit]

Code Snippet:

App.js

```
   return (
  <>
  <div>

  <BrowserRouter>
  
  {auth &&<DashBoard/>}
  <ToastContainer/>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/' element={<Login auth={setAuth}/>}/>
    <Route path='/admin' element={<Table/>}/>
    <Route path='/add' element={<AddUser/>}/>
  </Routes>
  
  </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
  </>
  );
```

AddUser.js

```
  const handleSubmit=(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    setData({...data,})
    console.log(data);
    axios.post('/add',data).then((response)=>{
      console.log("completed");
      toast.success("User Added Successfully");
    }).catch((error)=>{
      console.log("Not completed");
    })
  }
```

This is the Handle submit function in the Form

Comment: your question need more info for example what is your code?

Comment: yes i updated it with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same problem with you. This was because I mistakenly forgot to import the styles of `react-toastify`.

To solve this, you need to add this line in your `src/index.js`.

```
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css'
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 1):

I have an example and I hope it helps you :

```
// import tostify js and css
import {Slide, toast,ToastContainer} from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';

function Login(){


    const doLogin = (e)=>{
        
        if(username === '' || password == ''){
            toast.error('Username and Password is Required!', {
                position: "bottom-right",
                autoClose: 5000,
                hideProgressBar: false,
                closeOnClick: true,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                draggable: true,
                progress: undefined,
                theme: "colored",
            });
            return;
        }
        ....
    }

    return (<div className='user-login'>
        <div className='admin-panel'>
                ...
                <ToastContainer  transition={Slide}  />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>)
}
export default Login;
```